# Background image does not show properly

Tags: css

```css
.header {
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/43AFi.jpg');
  height: 83vh;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
jkjk
</div>
```

This is the complete image https://i.stack.imgur.com/43AFi.jpg
When using image src it shows without a problem https://jsfiddle.net/ohzcdav9/
but when using background image then this problem occurs. It should be 100% width and the whole image should show.

Comment: Based on your code, the whole image will never show. Your `header` is set to 83vh, so it will only be that tall. You have your background-size set to `cover`. This means your image will scale to fit the entire box at it's set ratio with the remainder hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You've set a `height` of `83vh`. Setting a `height` of `100vh` will allow the image to occupy the full browser `height`, and thus allow the full image to show, though it may distort the image based on your browser dimensions (due to `background-size: cover`).

Note that if you're using this as a full-page background, you'll also want to set `margin: 0` on `body` to avoid scrollbars, as can be seen in the following:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/kdsPrQt.jpg');
  height: 100vh;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/kdsPrQt.jpg');
  height: 100vh;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You should position you image bottom center as the bottom portion ocntains the curve, alos horizontally align the image center**

```css
.header {
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/kdsPrQt.jpg');
  height: 83vh;
  background-position: bottom center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
jkjk
</div>
```

**or disorting the image will help**

```css
.header1 {
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/kdsPrQt.jpg');
  height: 83vh;
  background-position: bottom center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header1">
jkjk
</div>
```